# Subtracting all elements in list from a specific number

Tags: python

Can I do an operation where I minus my list from a number using python? for example:

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I would then do `1 - a`

The output should be:

```
a = [-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

`a` in my code is a list of floats pulled from a .csv file, is this kind of operation possible in python?

I am creating my list this way:

```
f2 = 'C:/Users/.....csv'
with open(f2,'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in csvreader:
        l2.append(list(line))
```

`l2` contains lists of floats.

Comment: `l2` quite clearly contains lists: `l2.append(list(line))`

Comment: I meant the values themselves that make up the list are floats. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension

```
>>> values = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> [1 - value for value in values]
[-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

edit: If you really have a list of lists:

```
>>> values = [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
>>> [[1 - value for value in sublist]
...   for sublist in values]
[[-1, -3, -5], [-7, -9, -11]]
```

Comment: I tried this at first, it returns:  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: @MiguelA You have a typo somewhere, probably something like `[1 - values for value in values]`

Comment: I actually have a numpy array with rgba values in it. So `rgba_array[..., 0]` would access all red values. this would be an array of arrays.
I then did `print([255 - x for x in rgba_array[..., 0]])`
And it also seemed to work? I got the expected values.
However when doing this to a regular 2d array, I get a TypeError indeed.

Is this a overridden method for [integer] - [numpy arrays]?

Comment: @AgentM I don't know anything about `numpy`. I could look it up in the docs. If you want help on `numpy` though it would have been best to tag the original question, then you'd get experts on that to answer. Replying to me will get very few views from anyone else. Search the documentation, and stack overflow for other answers, and then maybe ask a new question if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you have plenty of options,

```
number = 1
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
result = list()
# using for loop
for i in a:
    result.append(number-i)

print result
# using list comprehension
result = [number-x for x in a]
print result

# taking functional approach and applying a lambda function on each element
result = map(lambda x: number - x, a)
print result
```

Please let me know if you need more explanation on each of them

#### edited. Can't comment so far, man :)

I bet you have a nested list, smth like [[1,2,3,4]] not the one [1,2,3,4].
If it is a case, try next

```
result = [1-x for y in a for x in y]
```

I know it looks horrible and it will help to make it cleaner if you post an actual list representation. You can fill a list with dummy values if it is important.

Comment: I'm still getting `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'` which is confusing because it works on the example but not on the list created from my .csv file

Comment: With your edit, the result will by a single dimension array, what if I want the same datatype namely, a 2d array from that operation?

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will do it:

```
atemp = [2,4,6,8,10]
a=[]
for i in atemp:
    a.append((1 - i))
```

Out:

```
[-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

Or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
a = [1 - x for x in atemp]
```

Out:

```
a

[-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub):

```
map(operator.sub, [1]*len(a), a)  # list(map(...)) for Python 3
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import operator
>>>
>>> a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> map(operator.sub, [1]*len(a), a)
[-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers here with python comprehension. If you are looking for Matlab-like equivalents, you could do it with the numpy library:

```
import numpy as np
list(np.ones(len(a)) - a)

[-1.0, -3.0, -5.0, -7.0, -9.0]
```

This will return floats by default. To get ints, use:

```
import numpy as np
list(np.ones(len(a), dtype=np.int) - a)

[-1, -3, -5, -7, -9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

```
values = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
x = [1 - value for value in values]
print(x)
```